# How to unnest sequence spec?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

with Clojure core.spec I can have the following:

```
(s/conform (s/cat :a even? :b (s/* odd?) :a2 even? :b2 (s/* odd?))  [2 3 5 12 13 15])
=> {:a 2, :b [3 5], :a2 12, :b2 [13 15]}
```

what I'd like to have is to remove redundancy by externalizing the sub spec:

```
(s/def ::even-followed-by-odds 
  (s/cat :a even? :b (s/* odd?)))
```

but

```
(s/conform (s/tuple ::even-followed-by-odds ::even-followed-by-odds)  [2 3 5 12 13 15])
=> :clojure.spec/invalid
```

this one works:

```
(s/conform (s/tuple ::even-followed-by-odds ::even-followed-by-odds)  [[2 3 5] [12 13 15]])
=> [{:a 2, :b [3 5]} {:a 12, :b [13 15]}]
```

So what I'm looking for is a function or macro (say unnest) which would it make work:

```
(s/conform (s/tuple (unnest ::even-followed-by-odds) (unnest ::even-followed-by-odds))  [2 3 5 12 13 15])
=> [{:a 2, :b [3 5]} {:a 12, :b [13 15]}]
```

how can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stay in regex op land:

```
(s/conform (s/cat :x ::even-followed-by-odds :y ::even-followed-by-odds) [2 3 5 12 13 15])

{:x {:a 2, :b [3 5]}, :y {:a 12, :b [13 15]}}
```

Comment: big thanks @alex-miller for your very prompt response.